# How do I get my characters hair, eyes and eyebrows to move in accordance to the head?

Tags: animation, rigging

I rigged my character, and when I move my head bone, my hair and eyes don't move. How do I fix this?

Comment: Move Particle modifier above Armature modifier ...?